# is there a list of the 93 vessels used in the temple daily?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, mishna, maseches-tamid

The mishna in tamid [3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Tamid.3.4?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Mishnah,_ed._Romm,_Vilna_1913&lang=bi) indicates there were 93 keilim used in the Beit HaMikdash daily. Is there a source which lists all 93?

Comment: I haven’t counted but would point you to the Mishnayot found in the beginning of Sefer Emek HaMelech. It is the listing of all the vessels which were hidden away before the destruction of the Temple. It is the same text that is found in the Copper Scroll which was discovered at Qumran.

Comment: It starts at the beginning of chapter 11.   http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7307&st=&pgnum=28

Comment: @YaacovDeane - I can't read your link, is there an English translation somewhere online?  I can definitely see some of the items on the Copper Scroll being on such a list, like(#12) "gold and silver vessels for tithe, sprinkling basins, sacrificial bowls, libation vessels-609 items(!)".  But they don't get too specific.  I would like to see both translations and see how they relate, though.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Sorry Gary. Perhaps someone in the community knows of one.

Comment: According to Tosafot Yom Tov on Tamid 3:4, the Mishnah means 93 of silver and 93 of gold for that particular action and that there were far more than 186 vessels. And that would seem to been what is described in the Mishnayot from Sefer Emek HaMelech.

Comment: The Bartenura already taught us that  לֹא אִתְפָּרֵשׁ לָמָּה הֻצְרְכוּ לְמִנְיָן שֶׁל כֵּלִים הַלָּלוּ - _nowhere is it explained why we need this specific amount of vessles_ - if he would have known of a list he could have figured it out. So any list find has to be recent (of Achronim vintage).

Comment: @DannySchoemann … or unknown to R. O. of Bartinura, or not agreed to by him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here (starting from the bottom of the right column) is a list of 31 vessels, with 3 of each, totaling 93.
[image: copy of sefer Tamid Yishtasheun quoting Ezras Kohanim]